# Docker Port Not Mapping

Tags: docker, aurelia

I'm sorry if this turns out to be obvious, but I'm having a hard time accessing a dockerized server from outside the container on the host.  Here's what I'm doing:

I'm running the container with the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name aurelia_dev -p 8888:8080 -v /Users/terskine/git/marvel/legendary:/app aurelia /bin/bash
```

Within the container I'm running the app:

```
cd app/
au run
```

In a separate terminal, I can see the container is running:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4b0a14bc6e88        aurelia             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp   aurelia_dev
```

However, I can't reach the server:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

But within the container, I can reach the server:

```
$ docker exec -it aurelia_dev /bin/bash
root@4b0a14bc6e88:/# curl http://localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html> ...
<html>
... [A whole bunch of HTML] ...
</html>
root@4b0a14bc6e88:/#
```

Why can't I access the server from outside the container on the host's port 8888?

I'm sure I'm missing an obvious step.  Please help me out.

Thanks!

---

Edit 1:
I don't think the following is necessary, but If it's helpful, I'm running a simple aurelia container which I created with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

RUN npm install -g aurelia-cli

CMD /bin/bash
```

The aurelia project that I'm running is the official tutorial project which can be found here: https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager

---

Edit 2:

This is the content of my hosts file.

```
root@d7d1cc03a5c0:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      d7d1cc03a5c0
```

And it would appear I'm not listening on `172.17.0.2:8080`

```
root@d7d1cc03a5c0:/# curl 172.17.0.2:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Comment: are you sure your application is listening on `0.0.0.0` and not just `localhost`?  Port maps require but don't affect whether the application is listening on , specifically (in your case) the ip on the default docker network.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I didn't realize that but I just ran `root@4b0a14bc6e88:/# curl http://0.0.0.0:8080` within the container and received the same HTML response, so it appears to be listening on `0.0.0.0`. Thanks for the idea.  Any others?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why "In practice connecting to 0.0.0.0 is equivalent to connecting to localhost".  Your test hasn't verified that you're not only listening on localhost.  It should be obvious in your code though, or you can check `netstat -l` or try your `curl` test on docker's private IP.

Comment: @DanielFarrell See `Edit 2` above.  Does that mean I'm not listening on `0.0.0.0`?  Is so, how do I fix that?

Comment: Yeah, you provided evidence that's your address inside the container (/etc/hosts) and showed you can't connect to it, so that's probably why the network map doesn't work.  From your `Dockerfile` it seems that something you typed once the docker container was created started a program that's listening on 8080.  Looks like it's this aurelia thing?  check its config documentation about how to listen to all addresses.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out not to be a problem with my Docker configuration.  Rather it was a problem with webpack, which is used by Aurelia. Webpack won't work with `localhost` in a docker container, please checkout [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/547#issuecomment-284737321).

To fix the problem, you must specify `0.0.0.0` as the host rather than using the default, which is `localhost`.

```
au run --host 0.0.0.0
```

Note: I asked a question about the real problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58685078/715608) and answered it, so it would be easier to find for others who have the same problem in the future, but I'm leaving this question because there may be people like me who think this is a docker config problem.

Comment: Similar thing when using Node's `http` module in the `listen` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered that on the other thread, but for other people just searching for an answer here it is:

you could override `host` and `port` in almost all aurelia commands, `au run` is one of those,

Examples:

`au run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7070`

`au run --watch --host 127.0.0.1 --port 7080`

the same set of flags also exists for `au cypress` and `au protractor`, besides, you can also tell `au` to bring up and tear down the application before and after running tests, again on a different port and IP address if you desired so.

Example:

`au cypress --run --start --port 7070 --host 127.0.0.1`

`au protractor --headless --start --port 7070 --host 127.0.0.1`

checkout [here](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/tree/master/skeleton/cypress) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/tree/master/skeleton/protractor)

Also, you could check the documentation on [Aurelia Build Systems](https://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/docker/setup) and my blog post on [Medium](https://medium.com/@shahabganji/dockerize-your-aurelia-application-9db72e70e4a2)