# Dockerized Aurelia App Is Not Visible Outside of Docker Container - Not listening on 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, aurelia

I'm running an Aurelia app inside of the standard node docker container and it is listening on port 8080.  Within the container, I have tested that it's running using `curl`; and it responds with the expected HTML.  But I cannot reach the app via the mapped port on the host (outside the container).

I'm running the following command to start the container

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v ${PWD}:/app node bash
```

Then inside the container, I install the cli and create a new app

```
# npm install -g aurelia-cli
# au new
```

After creating a default app, I `cd` into the app directory and run the app.

```
# au run
```

As I said above, I can verify the app is running using `curl http://localhost:8080`.  However, on the host, I cannot access the app:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Originally, I thought this was a docker problem.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58683987/715608).  But it turns out that Aurelia is listening on `localhost` rather than `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Have you tried “au run —host 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: And BTW, this is not related to Aurelia, AFAIK, it is webpack that needs to change the host to 0.0.0.0, for instance, if you create an Aurelia application with built-in bundler you won’t face such issue.

Comment: @SaeedGanji , `au run --host 0.0.0.0` fixed the problem without changing `webpack.config.js`.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Aurelia with the `host` option set allows the server to listen on `0.0.0.0`, so it will map properly in a docker container.

```
au run --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: No need to change webpack.config, just run Aurelia with host flag, or if you are willing to change the port as well pass port flag to the run command. au run —host 0.0.0.0 —port 7070